# Stream M3u url in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, m3u

I am trying to stream m3u from url. The below code is working with an MP3 url but no with an m3u url.

This is how I initialize the player

```
private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            // Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my listener for play button

```
radioPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        radioPlayButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);

        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am testing in an Android 4.1.2 API 16 device and I am getting

```
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), it's way better than MediaPlayer

Comment: @lelloman I've just search for ExoPlayer and it doesn't support m3u format. https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-formats.html

Comment: as far as I know m3u are just text files with a list of media sources, it shouldn't be that hard to extract them

Comment: and if I extract them how can I make it play with media player?

Comment: for m3u format you can look at the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), they basically contain a list of url with some headers